# how do I make thunderbird send outgoing mails with utf8 charset?

Tags: email, thunderbird

as I've seen with google this question was asked quite a few times in the past but since then the GUI of thunderbird changed so much, that those instructions can't be followed any more.

So my queston is: can I make thunderbird prefer utf8 as charset for outgoing mails instead of iso-8859-* ?

Thank you for your answer in advance.

Comment: In *Options* (AKA *Preferences*), on the *Composition* tab, select a font such as *Fixed Width*. Click *Send Options* ans select *Send messages as plain text if possible* and *Convert the message to plain text* for specified recipients, which can be specified by domain or through the Address Book. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setting your seeking is in the advanced Fonts & Colors settings in Thunderbird's General options, as indicated in the following marked-up screenshots (from Thunderbird 78.7.1 on Microsoft Windows 10):

[image: View of Options with General circled and an arrow pointing to the Advanced button in the Font & Colors section]

[image: View of Fonts & Encodings dialog box with default text encoding controls circled]

Comment: This answer is outdated. The menu has been removed in Thunderbird version 91